# How to insert character after text specifies in a string js?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a problem, i have a string like:

```
<div dir="ltr">adasdsad<div>dsadsadasd</div><div>sadasdsad</div></div>
```

and I want to inset `>` after `<div>` or `<dir="ltr">`. So result will be:

```
<div dir="ltr">>adasdsad<div>>dsadsadasd</div><div>>sadasdsad</div></div>
```

Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression of `/(\<div.*?\>)/g` to group all divs with any attributes (`.*?`), and then replace it with the captured group followed by a `>` by using `'$1>'` as the replacement argument

See example below:

```js
const str = '<div dir="ltr">adasdsad<div>dsadsadasd</div><div>sadasdsad</div></div>';

const res = str.replace(/(\<div.*?\>)/g, '$1>');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @NguyễnVŨ no worries ;)